# How to change the CSS class dynamically according to the angular expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change the span css class according to the angular expression.

if `{{pirstatus}} == 'Door Closed'` then class should be `class="label label-success"`
else it should be `class="label label-danger"`

```
<span class="label label-success" style="font-size:large">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

Comment: You may use `ng-class`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **`conditional class`**:

```
<span class="label {{pirstatus === 'Door Closed'? 'label-success': 'label-
danger'}}"  style="font-size:large">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

OR

```
<span class="label" ng-class="{true:'label-success', false: 'label-danger'}
[pirstatus === 'Door Closed']" style="font-size:large">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

Comment: The user had posted `Door` when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as you are looking for **AngularJs** code

```
<span class="label " ng-class="$pirstatus === 'Door Closed'? 'label-success': 'label-danger'>{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

*Dont forget to add a space after label in `class="label "`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`[ngClass]`**

```
<span class="label " [ngClass]="pirstatus === 'Door Closed'? 'label-success':
 'label-danger'">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

OR

```
<span class="label " [ngClass]="'label-success':pirstatus === 'Door
 Closed','label-danger':pirstatus !== 'Door Closed'">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class binding `[class]` as

```
<span [class]="pirstatus == 'Door Closed' ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger'" 
style="font-size:large">{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

Or, you can use conditional as

```
<span class="label" [class.label-success]="pirstatus == 'Door Closed'" 
[class.label-danger]="pirstatus !== 'Door Closed'" style="font-size:large">
{{pirstatus}}</span>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing both cases](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-class-binding?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply go with the condition classes in AngularJS

`<span ng-class="{'class1':a==true,'class2':a==false }" style="font-size:large">{{pirstatus}}</span>`

Here a == true or a == false is the condition you want to check.